# STDIN not getting attached to restarted docker container

Tags: go, docker

If a container is stopped and started again, the data on the STDIN attached is passed to the container only during the first start. On all subsequent starts, no data is found on the STDIN.

I'm using `fsouza/go-dockerclient`. Any help would be appreciated on this. I found a related [issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4487), but it does not lead anywhere. If this behavior is intended, what are the workarounds, if any? I need to have two phases of the container, with different STDIN data each time.

Comment: Can you show an example of what's not working? It hard to check what you might be doing wrong without knowing what you're doing. There's no reason you can't attach stdin when starting a container a second time, as it's the same process as starting it the first time.